# Relationship between adding total time derivative to a Lagrangian and symmetry transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem, boundary-terms

Given the Lagrangian $L(x(t),\dot{x}(t),t)$ one can perform an infinitesimal transformation
\begin{align*}
    x &\mapsto x' = x + \delta x  \\
    t &\mapsto t' = t + \delta t 
\end{align*}

Say $\delta x \sim \epsilon$ and $\delta t \sim \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \ll 1$. Then the Lagrangian changes also infinitesimally, as
\begin{equation*}
    L \mapsto L'=L + \delta L
\end{equation*}

Imposing this transformation to be a symmetry, i.e. the action
\begin{equation*}
    S[x,t] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \, L(x(t),\dot{x}(t),t)
\end{equation*}

does not change under the transformation ($S'[x',t']=S[x',t']$), the most general form of the new lagrangian is (up to constant)
\begin{equation*}
    L ' = L + \frac{d}{dt} \delta G
\end{equation*}

where $G(x,t)$ is some arbitrary function and again $\delta G \sim \epsilon$. Recall adding total time derivative to a Lagrangian does not change the action. Consequently, the so-called symmetry test must hold identically:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \delta t + L \frac{d}{d t} \delta t + \frac{d}{d t} \delta G = 0 
\end{equation*}

Now, consider a lagrangian $L$
\begin{equation*}
    L = L' + \frac{d}{dt}F(x,t)
\end{equation*}

with $F(x,t)$ being some function (not infinitesimal this time!). My question is: **how are $G(x,t)$ and $F(x,t)$ related? Can we interpret $G$ as a generator?**

For instance, the Lagrangian
\begin{equation*}
    L = \frac{1}{2}\, \dot{x}^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} + 2x\dot{x}t + x^2
\end{equation*}

has a symmetry given by $\delta x = \epsilon \, x$, $\delta t = 2\,\epsilon \, t$ and $\delta G = -4\, \epsilon \, x^2\, t$ because the symmetry test holds. But we can also think this lagrangian as
\begin{equation*}
    L = \frac{1}{2}\, \dot{x}^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{d}{dt}\left( x^2\, t \right)
\end{equation*}
Identifying here $F=x^2\, t$. The deepest relation I could found is that $\delta F + \delta G = 0$. What does it mean?